Would an 'altered' package be replaced by an updated version when it comes out?
I'm currently experimenting with ksmbd. The current build of ksmbd tools in ubuntu 24.04 has broken packaging and install fails - I ended up downloading the deb-src and building a package with the changes suggested here. I'm not asking how to fix it.
I didn't change the version and such. I edited the package, used apt to install the modified package explicitly and it works fine
geek@testbox:~$ apt info ksmbd-tools
Package: ksmbd-tools
Version: 3.5.1-1build2
Priority: optional
Section: universe/utils
Origin: Ubuntu

This is what I have now.
ksmbd tends to have quite a few security issues and while I'm running this on a closed off network, with decent security - I'd like to update to a officially supported, in repository version once its sorted, but start using it now. Would an updated version in a repository  simply replace the one I have once the packaging is fixed?

quick note for any other poor soul who does this - when I try to update , the repo version clobbers the repackaged version which breaks ksmbd, so I guess the answer is "yes, whether you like it or not" ._.

Since you haven't altered the version (I see the package index also says 3.5.1-1build2), when a new version is finally released, apt will prefer it over the installed version - provided, however, that you haven't pinned or held the package. Typically people who want to avoid the update do so, or fudge the version string (usually by adding an epoch prefix).
